# scikit-learn: filling missing values by random sampling

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am surprised that [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) does not offer the following strategy for filling missing values: For any missing value, sample uniformly at random one value from the given values and replace.

I assume that this is a better strategy than replacing with the mean, the most frequent or the median value, as it does not produce an artificial spike in the distribution of values.

Do I need to write a transformer that does this myself?

ps. On a more meta-level of discussion, I am always a bit puzzled when I do not find what I consider a straightforward, almost standard operation as a component in a library like `scikit-learn`. Makes me wonder: Is this library very unfinished or am I trying to do something that is against best practices? Any advice?

Comment: You would need a local window which defines the uniform distribution to sample from in order to prevent spiking as well? Maybe you are searching for (linear) interpolation?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem you are pointing to. The imputation strategy does not need to be perfect in terms of preserving the distribution, just less obviously bad than mean, median, most frequent. Doesn't random sampling achieve this?

Comment: This depends on the distribution you sample from, I would say. How do you want to define it? Anyway, it seems that you are imposing some kind of temporal relation of the individual entries you are operating on? Imputing the mean is a good candidate in case there is no such relation. However, for time series data there might be better methods.

Comment: It's not a time series, no temporal relation intended.

Comment: Is there really a problem with those spikes when the classifier has some discriminative nature? Is it really better than adding noise? (When it's not within sklearn i expect it to be not that important to most users and/or not much backup through scientific work; of course it does not mean it would not be a good adding)

Answer (score 1):

For discrete numeric series random sampling from the existing values may be better than using mean or median which will replace all missing value to a single number and definitely bring an artificial spike to the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that this is a better strategy than replacing with the mean, the most frequent or the median value, as it does not produce an artificial spike in the distribution of values.

Unfortunately this is wrong. When you know nothing about the distribution of a continous variable, the best guess is **always** the mean, because it's less likely to introduce bias in your data.

If you instead decide to fill the missing values with random sampling from *any* distribtution, you are invariably assuming that distribution as the one generating the observations. Hence, introducing clear bias in your dataset.

However, you might have a look a the [sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html#sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer)
 which provides a more complex approach to imputing.

Comment: Could you prove your point by linking to literature? As far as I remember, the best strategy for imputation depends highly on what you want to do. If you want to estimate the mean, yes, mean imputation is the way to go. If you want to estimate covariance.... I have doubts.

Comment: When you fill with the observed mean, you are simply "sampling" from a distribution whose mean is the observed sample mean, and which has no variance to speak of. This is also certainly not the distribution generating the observations!

Answer (score 0):

I am arriving a bit late to this discussion, but since I saw it, I thought I'd add my 2 cent.

With the open-source Python library Feature-engine, we can perform random sample imputation right away. I leave here a link to the [RandomSampleImputer](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_doc/imputation/RandomSampleImputer.html).

In the following snippet I show that the functionality is very similar to that of Scikit-learn transformers:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from feature_engine.imputation import RandomSampleImputer

X = pd.DataFrame(dict(

       x1 = [np.nan,1,1,0,np.nan],

       x2 = ["a", np.nan, "b", np.nan, "a"],

       ))

rsi = RandomSampleImputer()

rsi.fit(X)

rsi.transform(X)
```

The output will be:

```
    x1 x2
0  1.0  a
1  1.0  b
2  1.0  b
3  0.0  a
4  1.0  a
```

where the missing data were replaced by random samples extracted from the original variables (where values were available).

Regarding this method not being included in Scikit-learn, the developers like including methods that are well (scientifically, when possible) documented. and this is not one of them.

I'd also say that this is not a standard method of imputation. When talking about simple univariate methods, the most widely used are mean, median, mode, and arbitrary imputation.

This method does preserve the variable distribution (for all distributions), because a random sample of a variable will show the same distribution by definition. But, on the downside, it has an element of randomness that is difficult to account for, particularly, when we want to put the models into production.

In an extreme example, say we have 2 patients that show identical data in 9 out of 10 variables, and the value in the 10th variable is missing. When we carry out random imputation, most likely, each patient will receive a different value, which will, in turn, lead to a different prediction. And, this is a no-go, in terms of being fair to our customers. In short, we would be offering different solutions, to patients that show identical characteristics.

In addition, when or if we put the model into production, in order to extract random samples, we would have to store a copy of the training dataset, which, if big, could be quite memory-intensive.